# Creating a customer client in Google Ads test account: CUSTOMER_NOT_ALLOWLISTED_FOR_THIS_FEATURE

Tags: node.js, google-ads-api, adsense

I am trying to create a customer client in my Google Ads test account but I receive the following error:

```
{"errors":[{"error_code":{"not_allowlisted_error":"CUSTOMER_NOT_ALLOWLISTED_FOR_THIS_FEATURE"},"message":"Customer is not allowlisted for accessing this feature."}],"request_id":"ApWtRj1nJ19MiT-I2Y3EoA"}
```

This is my code for creating the customer client (I am using the **google-ads-api** library)

```
const client = new GoogleAdsApi({
    client_id,
    client_secret,
    developer_token
});

let managerId = "xxx";
let testAccountId = "xxx";
let refreshToken = "xxx";
const customer = client.Customer({
    login_customer_id: testAccountId,
    customer_id: testAccountId,
    refresh_token
});
const response = await customer.customers.createCustomerClient({
    customer_id: managerId,
    customer_client: {
        currency_code: "EUR",
        descriptive_name: "My customer client",
        time_zone: "Europe/London",
        resource_name: `customers/${managerId}`
    },
    email_address: "test@test.io",
    access_role: "STANDARD",
    validate_only: false,
    toJSON: null,
});
console.log("response:", response);
```

This only thing I can find about it is here: [1]: https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/reference/rpc/v5/NotAllowlistedErrorEnum.NotAllowlistedError

But it does not clarify anything. I can also not test it on my production Google Ads account since my developer token has to been validated.

Why can't I create a customer client account?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have to create new client accounts via the web UI if you're using a test manager account.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Dave. If I try this in the web UI it gives me an error I have to add billing information. Then if I want to add billing information it gives me an error I can't add billing information on a test account...